# AWS cloudwatch alarm using CLI for EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-emr

How to write a cloudwatch alarm for EMR using CLI command??

My requirement is to terminate cluster which are idle for more than 2hours. I need to do this using aws CLI command.

Comment: Are you just asking how to terminate the cluster from the CLI, or are you asking how to automatically detect that it is idle and _then_ terminate it?

Answer (score 0):

From [Monitor Metrics with CloudWatch - Amazon EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/UsingEMR_ViewingMetrics.html):

> The `IsIdle` metric tracks whether a cluster is live, but not currently running tasks. You can set an alarm to fire when the cluster has been idle for a given period of time, such as thirty minutes.

Therefore, you can configure an alarm on this metric. However, the alarm itself is not able to terminate an Amazon EMR cluster. You would need an additional component, such as an AWS Lambda function, to actually terminate the cluster.

The components would be:

- An Amazon CloudWatch `IsIdle` **metric** (automatically provided)
- An **Alarm** on the metric that triggers when the cluster is idle for longer than the desired period
- Configure the Alarm to send a message to an **Amazon SNS topic**
- Create an AWS Lambda function and **subscribe** the function to the SNS topic
- Code the Lambda function to **terminate** the Amazon EMR cluster

There is a more complex version of this auto-shutdown process documented at: [Optimize Amazon EMR costs with idle checks and automatic resource termination using advanced Amazon CloudWatch metrics and AWS Lambda | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/optimize-amazon-emr-costs-with-idle-checks-and-automatic-resource-termination-using-advanced-amazon-cloudwatch-metrics-and-aws-lambda/)